# how to change int value on label text every time when button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

//HERE IS THE CODE I HAVE ALSO USED COLOR LABEL IN STRING

```
var cellIndex: Int = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cellIndex = 1
    let s1 = "word \(cellIndex) to \(cellIndex+7)"
    let mystring:NSString = "\(s1) recovery phrases" as NSString
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    myMutableString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:mystring as String, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Font.mediumRegularFont()])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: Color.darkColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:s1.count))
    stepBarView.attributedText = myMutableString
}
@IBAction func onNextButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    // i want to change cellIndex Value every time when i press button.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1 replace the value with **replacingOccurrences** but need to consider how many digits the number may have.
2 recreate the whole string again which is faster and less work

Answer (score 0):

You can use didSet inside cellIndex.

```
var cellIndex: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        let s1 = "word \(cellIndex) to \(cellIndex+7)"
        let mystring:NSString = "\(s1) recovery phrases" as NSString
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        myMutableString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:mystring as String, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:Font.mediumRegularFont()])
       myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: Color.darkColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:s1.count))
        stepBarView.attributedText = myMutableString
    }
}
```

Now, whenever value is set to cellIndex, it will update the label with desired string.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the exact functioning of didset?

Comment: It gets called after the value is assigned the variable.

Comment: Good Solution .. (y)